# PHP ZF Importing data into Zend_Config from database - magento style configurations

Tags: database, zend-framework, configuration

So I have a database table called configs that has the following columns - key and value.

The key looks like so 'core/database/params/username' and the value is 'root'. I want to be able to access this from a Zend_Config object using $config->core->database->params->username. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your custom class My_Config_Database extending Zend_Config and implement any logic you want ;) Zend_Config_Ini is easy to understand and refactor for your needs ;)

Comment: You're welcome. You might consider caching the resulting config, because the config generation might be a bottleneck (if you're not lazy-loading the values)

Comment: I am planning on doing that. Thanks again for the assistance!